# Android KitKat get Toast radius?

Tags: android, android-toast

Im using the library by [RomainNurik](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar) to show an Undo-Toast to the user (like in the Gmail app)

Prior to KitKat the toast option was rectangular, and in KitKat there toast message has rounded corners. 
Is there a get() method to get the Radius of the Toast? So that if im using the library,I can getRadius() ,and adjust my toast according to that?

Note: Otherwise I would have to specify two differnt values, one prior to KitKat and one for KitKat.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is `android:shadowRadius` of the Toast which is `2.75` in the layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:attr/toastFrameBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Toast"
        android:textColor="@color/bright_foreground_dark"
        android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
        android:shadowRadius="2.75"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I found it in `Android SDK\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\layout` named `transient_notification.xml`